# this property is not supported by object?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                ('#mainField').click(function(){
                    $("#editor").animate({width: 985, height: 200}, 1500);
                    $("#closeEditor").css("display", "inline");
                });
            });
```

This piece of code doesn't work, whats wrong?!
It says: "this property is not supported by object" at the 2nd row..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`('#mainField')`

404 No dollar found.